# Copying text field into Input fields

Tags: jquery, input, copy

I am trying to take a series of Inputs and replace them using a button with a list of text. I realize it could be easily achieved by using ID's but I have to account for the fact that it can be expandable (meaning could be 1 or could be 5). I started down the road of an .each loop to iterate over the inputs and get their values, but how can I also iterate over the text values and put them in the right input?

Here is where i got stuck:

```
jQuery('.copy-btn').on("click", function (e) {
var selector = "[class^=span]";
var $this = jQuery(this);
var $pristine = jQuery(".field-item");
var $first = $this.closest(selector).prev(selector);
var $second = $this.closest(selector).next(selector);

if ($first.find("div").hasClass("field-name-field-mg-features-list")) {
    var one = $first.find(".form-type-textfield input.text-full").each(function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
    });
    var two = $second.find(".field-item").each(function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
    });
    var $input = $this.find(".form-type-textfield input.text-full");
    var $text = $this.find(".field-item");
} else {
    $first.find("input").val($second.find($pristine).text());
}
e.preventDefault(e);

});
```

I also don't think this is the best practice for achieving my desired behavior, can someone point me in the right direction?

http://jsfiddle.net/nmfurr/nA37d/250/

Comment: Can you explain better which text you want to put where, which button you mean also.

Comment: sure, the button I'd like to cause the value change is the "copy" button in the fiddle. and the change i'd like to see is "Thing 1, thing 2, and thing 3" being replaced with "A, B, and C" from the bottom field set.

Comment: Ok, what is Thing? what is A,B,C? I  see no class called span like you have in your selector `[class^=span]`. Explain a bit better and we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

If they correspond to index location on the dom I think you could do

```
jQuery('.copy-btn').on("click", function (e) {
   var count = $("field-name-field-mg-features-list").size();
   var fields = $("form-type-textfield input.text-full");
   var text = $("field-item")
   var x = 0;
   for (x=0;x++;x<count){
       fields[x].val(text[x].text())
   }
   e.preventDefault(e);

});
```